# OSRM-extract Sorting edges by start seems to stop

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine, pbf

I try to use planet-latest.osm.pbf (2018-05-23) from https://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/.

I extract the pbf file on Ubuntu 16.04 and everything seems OK until *Sorting edges by start ...*

On internet, I saw that this operation takes usually only few seconds. But my server has been running it for more than 5 hours.

Should I just wait or has something gone wrong ?

Comment: What are the specs of your machine?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I finally found a solution and you're right. This is because my machine isn't enough powerful. So now I use Graphhopper and it works well.